# How do I resolve Debian packaging issue with ${python:Depends}?

Tags: python, packaging, deb

I am trying to build a python-based Debian package and I see the `${python:Depends}` variable under the Depends section in the control file.

While installing, I see that it refers to the `python-alembic` package as a dependency, but I cannot understand how or where this variable gets populated.

Basically, I wanted to change the name here from `python-alembic` to `alembic` under the depends section coz I don't have the package with name `python-alembic`.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely from `dh_python2`, which guesses dependencies based on the `requires.txt` file in `egg_info`. This file is created from `install_requires` in `setup.py` by distutils / setuptools.

You can disable reading `requires.txt` by putting:

```
override_dh_python2:
    dh_python2 --no-guessing-deps
```

in your `debian/rules`. Or you can help it by putting

```
alembic alembic
```

in `debian/pydist-overrides` (I think).